# i have proplem with js code querySelectorAll didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, queryselector

I have a problem with the `querySelectorAll` function. It doesn't work. I try to `console.log("any text");` and it works. The following code doesn't work:

```
nav = document.querySelectorAll("a");
console.log(nav)
nav.forEach(a => {
    console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: Most likely `document.querySelectorAll("a")` doesn't match anything.

Comment: you could also use  `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` if you are just trying to get anchor tags

Comment: What is the error message? Can you provide a minimal example including the html?